# Muscular guy built up calves of steel by carrying buckets of water up and down stairs at state prison?

Tags: calf

A friend of mine, while serving his prison sentence, claims he was able to build his calf muscles by carrying heavy buckets of water up and down the stairs. Is this possible?

Comment: It's certainly plausible.You can actually build some impressive calf muscles by regularly walking up and down stairs with weights. It also builds your endurance.

Comment: What does drug possession(heroin) have to do the with question?  What part is fishy?  He carried buckets or the guards made him?

Comment: @Frisbee, the main question is still whether carrying heavy objects up and down the stairs will build calves muscle. Though, I would prefer if he wrote the question instead of the story.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's entirely possible.

The main function of the calves (Gastrocnemius and soleus) is to plantar flex (point) the feet.

So, as you step up, you dorsiflex your foot slightly, then push up with your thighs and calves to elevate to the next step. Do this over and over, and you will build solid calves.